# Function using dialog boxes incorrectly executing false statements

Tags: r, function

I am writing a function which will connect an R session to one of a number of Oracle databases. Within this function, the user must *always* input their username and password, but *may not* need to input the host name/port number, depending on whether these parameters are already programmed into the function. If the host/port is not included in the function, then the user will be prompted to input these parameters manually.

For whatever reason, my function is mistakenly executing false statements and forcing the user to input the host name/port numbers, despite the fact that they are using a pre-programmed database. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? Driving me proper nuts right now...

See below for sample code. For some reason, the **only** one that is executing correctly is the last database (DB4).

```
library(svDialogs)
library(getPass)

db_function <- function(database) {
  login_1 <- dlg_input(message = paste("Input", database, "Username:"), Sys.info()["login_1"])$res
  login_2 <- getPass(msg = paste("Input", database, "Password:"))
  if(database == "DB1") {
    host <- "host1"
    port <- 9999
  }
  if(database == "DB2") {
    host <- "host2"
    port <- 9999
  }
  if(database == "DB3") {
    host <- "host3"
    port <- 9999
  }
  if(database == "DB4") {
    host <- "host4"
    port <- 9999
  }
  else {
    host <- dlg_input(message = paste("Input", database, "Host Name:"),
                      Sys.info()["host"])$res
    port <- dlg_input(message = paste("Input", database, "Port Number:"),
                      Sys.info()["port"])$res
  }
  connect_string <- paste(
    "(DESCRIPTION=",
    "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=", host, ")(PORT=", port, "))",
    "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=", database, ")))", sep = "")
}

## executes incorrectly (programmed but still prompted to input manually)    
db_function("DB3")

## executes correctly (programmed and not prompted to input manually)
db_function("DB4")

## executes correctly (not programmed, so prompted to input manually)
db_function("DB5")
```

Thanks much for any help anyone can offer on this!

Comment: Because the first 3 `if` statements are not followed by `else`, they "end" and are not connected to the `else` statement, they're separate and self-contained. You can turn them into a connected chain using `if (condition1) { ... } else if (condition2) {...} else {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned this should solve it

```
library(svDialogs)
library(getPass)

db_function <- function(database) {
  login_1 <- dlg_input(message = paste("Input", database, "Username:"), Sys.info()["login_1"])$res
  login_2 <- getPass(msg = paste("Input", database, "Password:"))
  if(database == "DB1") {
    host <- "host1"
    port <- 9999
  } else
  if(database == "DB2") {
    host <- "host2"
    port <- 9999
  } else
  if(database == "DB3") {
    host <- "host3"
    port <- 9999
  } else
  if(database == "DB4") {
    host <- "host4"
    port <- 9999
  }
  else {
    host <- dlg_input(message = paste("Input", database, "Host Name:"),
                      Sys.info()["host"])$res
    port <- dlg_input(message = paste("Input", database, "Port Number:"),
                      Sys.info()["port"])$res
  }
  connect_string <- paste(
    "(DESCRIPTION=",
    "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=", host, ")(PORT=", port, "))",
    "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=", database, ")))", sep = "")
}

## executes incorrectly (programmed but still prompted to input manually)    
db_function("DB3")

## executes correctly (programmed and not prompted to input manually)
db_function("DB4")

## executes correctly (not programmed, so prompted to input manually)
db_function("DB5")
```

Comment: Smh. It's always the simplest things. Thanks so much Bruno + Marius!